# Transferring a 2D array to another, dividing numbers in two

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following task:
The user has entered an array - A[m][n]; transform this array to a new one, keeping only the lines that are odd and each element should be divided in two.
I know it is simple but can not figure out how to do it, so please lend a hand.
P.S. The array should be with pointers
P.S.S. The program should work as follows.
If for exaple there is this array inputted:
1 2 3 4 5
5 4 3 2 1
9 2 3 5 1
2 3 4 6 7
It should then output this
0.5 1 1.5 2 2.5
4.5 1 1.5 2.5 0.5

So, I made it without pointers but have problems to remake it using pointers. How would they change the following code?

```
 #include <iostream>

using namespace std;



int main()
{
    int m,n;
    cin>>m>>n;
    int matrix[m][n];

    for(int x=0; x<m; x++)
    {
        for(int y=0; y<n; y++)
        {
            cin>>matrix[x][y];

        }
    }



    for(int x=0; x<m; x=x+2)
    {
        for(int y=0; y<n; y++)
        {
            cout<<(matrix[x][y])/2<<" ";

        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you made an attempt yet? If so, please show the code and explain what does not work.

Comment: The rule here is to show some efforts, before asking something. Everybody is eager to help, but without showing some _relevant_ code, it appears that you're asking us to do your task/homework/etc

Comment: Please, show the code and tell what means the <<lines are odd>>?

Comment: Well, I only figured out that to work, I need to copy every next line in the new array, dividing the numerals in two. What could be an effective way of copying the array, however with no integrated functions?

Comment: Do you know how to display a matrix ? If yes, then, this shouldn't be a difficult task. Hint :- Find the odd rows and display is element after dividing by 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for showing some efforts !

And regarding your  *"...have problems to remake it using pointers"*

Just change
`matrix[x][y]` to `*(*(matrix+x)+y)`

Also since you need decimal values, use `2.0` for division

`cout << *(*(matrix+x)+y)/2.0 << " " ;`

For details about these representation refer a good book or search it on SO